# Is using StringUtils.EMPTY recommended in unit test where StringUtils.isBlank method is used?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, apache-stringutils

I have function

```
public void foo(final String s) {
  if(StringUtils.isBlank(s) {//throw error}
  //rest of the logic
}
```

and unit test

```
@Test(//expected exception)
public void testFooWithBlankString() {
   ClassOfFoo.foo(StringUtils.EMPTY);
}
```

Is this correct?
Should I create a blank variable like

```
BLANK = "   "
```

and use that in unit test?

Comment: I think isBlank checks for whitespace, length 0 and null whereas empty checks for string of length 0 or null. So it depends on the purpose of your check.

Answer (score 1):

[StringUtils.isBlank()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) checks for three things:

- length = 0
- null
- whitespace `("   ")`

[StringUtils.EMPTY](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#EMPTY) = "". So if you want to check for empty String then go for this but if you consider whitespace `("   ")` to be checked as well then use isBlank().

Comment: good answer. OP should consider using Theories to pass in all values that should cause the exception